# Data Factory activity to convert in proper json

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am running my ADF pipeline with Dataflow and I am getting the output as json as something like this

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"[vaq:233,popo:basic5542]"}
```

However, my actual requirement is to have something like this.

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":["vaq:233","popo:basic5542"]}
```

Check the placement of double inverted commas for key "key2".In my Data factory pipeline I am using Derived column action in Dataflow and for key2 I am doing `concat ("[",Data1,",popo:basic5542]" )` and Data1 has value vaq:233.

How can I adjust the double inverted comma here?

Comment: is `popo:basic5542` a static value or are getting that dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you use the below expression and check whether this meets your requirement.

```
array(Data1,"popo:basic5542")
```

Instead of the concat function.

**Output :**

> ["pea:P1013","popo:basic5542"]

Answer (score 0):

Considering `popo:basic5542` is a static value, you can try as below expression.

```
concat("[","\"",Data1,"\"",",","\"","popo:basic5542","\"","]")
```

Or if you are getting `popo` and `basic5542` dynamically, you can try as below.

```
concat("[","\"",Data1,"\"",",","\"",popo,":",basic5542,"\"","]")
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: popo:basic5542 is static value but Data1 is a column whose value is being taken. The above syntax is not correct can you please recheck?

Comment: In my example, `FirstName,` , `MiddleName` and `LastName` are all columns. If popo:basic5542 is static, you just have to mention between double quotes. I've edited. in 1st expression suggested. `"popo:basic5542"`

Comment: I made it to parse and was able to fix the syntax but the output I get has the escape characters. its like this: "key1":"[\"value1\",\"popo:basic5542\"]"}

Comment: did you run and see the output?

Comment: yes, it is same as you can see the data preview in my screenshot

Comment: you can further use, function `unescape` see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#unescape

Comment: well I tried all and for some reason I am unable to remove "\" from my output

Comment: ok, i just checked and even for me in Data preview the parsing is successful and I get text without any "\" but once I output it to a JSOn sink I get the "\" character back in my string

Comment: it seems to be by design, I don't see any explicit function in data flow. `Replace` and `unescape` are function made for this scenario but the final result is same. DO share if you find a way around this